# Is it possible to download an entire Big Query Database?

Tags: google-bigquery

For example would it be possible to download the entirety of bigquery-public-data:chicago_taxi_trips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the  bigquery-public-data:chicago_taxi_trips:

1. Go to [Google Cloud Public Datasets](https://cloud.google.com/public-datasets/)
2. Search for dataset (chicago taxi trips)
3. Select View Dataset
4. Select bigquery-public-data/chicago_taxi_trips/taxi_trips
5. Select Export/Export to GCS
6. Select GCS location , Export format, Compression.

Using CLI

```
    bq --location=location extract \
    --destination_format format \
    --compression compression_type \
    --field_delimiter delimiter \
    --print_header=boolean \
    project_id:dataset.table \
    gs://bucket/filename.ext
```

> Where:
>
> location is the name of your location. The --location flag is
>   optional. For example, if you are using BigQuery in the Tokyo region,
>   you can set the flag's value to asia-northeast1. You can set a default
>   value for the location using the .bigqueryrc file.
>
> format is the format for the exported data: CSV,
>   NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON, or AVRO.
>
> compression_type is a supported compression type for your data format.
>   CSV and NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON support GZIP. AVRO supports DEFLATE and
>   SNAPPY.
>
> delimiter is the character that indicates the boundary between columns
>   in CSV exports. \t and tab are accepted names for tab.
>
> boolean is true or false. When set to true, header rows are printed to
>   the exported data if the data format supports headers. The default
>   value is true.
>
> project_id is your project ID.
>
> dataset is the name of the source dataset.
>
> table is the table you're exporting.
>
> bucket is the name of the Cloud Storage bucket to which you're
>   exporting the data. The BigQuery dataset and the Cloud Storage bucket
>   must be in the same location.
>
> filename.ext is the name and extension of the exported data file. You
>   can export to multiple files using a wildcard.

[Exporting table data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will first need to export to Google Cloud Storage, and then you would download from there.

Another option would be to write a script (python or R) to query the data, and then you could write the results to file.  Note, for big datasets, it might be more helpful to query in chunks.